# Github actions not working properly with repository secrets

Tags: react-native, android-studio, github-actions

I have made github actions and written code for react native in .yml file

I need to pass security secret actions but I am not able to access Repository secrets appid and password and I need to pass that in action script but I m not able to access that

Created action script and getting error like:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project '***'.

> Could not get unknown property 'application_id' for Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.

can someone guide me right method to pass repository secrets

help will be much appreciated

I have already added secrets in actions secrets but unable to fetch in action script,

```
- run: |
          cd project_name && yarn  
          cd android
          ./gradlew clean build
          -PAPPLICATION_ID=$APPLICATION_ID // name from action secrets ID
          -PPASSWORD=$PASSWORD // name from action secrets Password
```

Comment: Have you export the secrets as environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

an easy way to set secrets value as environment variables, you could simply do:

```
- name: build
  env:
    APPLICATION_ID: ${{  secrets. APPLICATION_ID }}
    PASSWORD: ${{  secrets. PASSWORD }}
  run: |
          cd project_name && yarn  
          cd android
          ./gradlew clean build
          -PAPPLICATION_ID=$APPLICATION_ID // name from action secrets ID
          -PPASSWORD=$PASSWORD // name from action secrets Password
```

Comment: I already added env variables ,  
- name: Install npm dependencies
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
         APPLICATION_ID: ${{  secrets. APPLICATION_ID }}
    PASSWORD: ${{  secrets. PASSWORD }}
        env:
           APPLICATION_ID: ${{  secrets. APPLICATION_ID }}
    PASSWORD: ${{  secrets. PASSWORD }}
     run: |
          cd project_name && yarn  
          cd android
          ./gradlew clean build
          -PAPPLICATION_ID=$APPLICATION_ID // name from action secrets ID
          -PPASSWORD=$PASSWORD // name from action secrets Password

Comment: Add the env to the run step

Comment: you could also put the `env` section at `job` level

Comment: already tried but still not working